# wpdb COALESCE won't work

Tags: query, mysql, wpdb

I am struggling to get the result using `COALESCE` from custom table. I need to run a second query if the first results null but `wpdb` resulting query string itself rather than the result.

```
$query = "SELECT coalesce(";
$query .= "(SELECT order_number FROM wp_gs_p_cart ";
$query .= "WHERE group_user = %d AND group_id = %d AND identifier = %s ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1),";
$query .= "(SELECT order_number FROM wp_gs_p_cart ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)";
$query .= ");";

$prepare = $wpdb->prepare($query, $user_id, $group_id, $identifier);

return $wpdb->get_results($prepare);

// or 

return $wpdb->get_row($prepare);
```

#### Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [coalesce((SELECT order_number FROM wp_gs_p_cart WHERE group_user = 73 AND group_id = 298 AND identifier = 'AtR4deAVgU4Ensi1_1ac2b33a4df7c5f0cf148d6232074352' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1),(SELECT order_number FROM wp_gs_p_cart ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1))] => 3333
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could see, the query did return a result, but the `COALESCE()` result was not named, hence MySQL and WordPress use the entire `COALESCE()` query as the field name.

To avoid that, you would use an *alias* for the `COALESCE()`, e.g.

```php
//$query = "SELECT COALESCE( <your queries> ) AS <alias>";
$query = "SELECT COALESCE( NULL, 5, 2, 3 ) AS order_number";

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
// Assuming $results[0] exists:
echo $results[0]->order_number;

$result = $wpdb->get_row( $query );
// Assuming the query returned a result:
echo $result->order_number;
```

But since `COALESCE()` returns just one result, you'd want to use `get_var()`:

```php
//$query = "SELECT COALESCE( NULL, 5, 2, 3 )"; // this works
// But maybe, better with an alias.
$query = "SELECT COALESCE( NULL, 5, 2, 3 ) AS order_number";

$result = $wpdb->get_var( $query );
echo $result;
```

Comment: Perfect...!!! Thanks a lot :)